# How can I resolve this build issue? MSBuild Error: MSB4216

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm trying to build a dotnet project, and I don't believe there is anything wrong with the project file. I suspect it is something wrong with my environment. Currently I am using windows 10. Below is the error I received and the project file. I should also mention I am performing this through CLI

Console Output

```
PS C:\Users\Jon\WowFishingAssist> dotnet build .\WowFishingAssist.sln
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3032,5): error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run. [C:\Users\Jon\WowFishingAssist\WowFishingAssist\WowFishingAssist.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3032,5): error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run. [C:\Users\Jon\WowFishingAssist\WowFishingAssist\WowFishingAssist.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.69
PS C:\Users\Jon\WowFishingAssist>
```

csproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{BDE46AC5-715B-4700-AB85-A31D0412507F}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>WowFishingAssist</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WowFishingAssist</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <DisableOutOfProcTaskHost>true</DisableOutOfProcTaskHost>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DisableOutOfProcTaskHost>true</DisableOutOfProcTaskHost>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DisableOutOfProcTaskHost>true</DisableOutOfProcTaskHost>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>
    </StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AForge, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c1db6ff4eaa06aeb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AForge.2.2.5\lib\AForge.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AForge.Imaging.2.2.5\lib\AForge.Imaging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AForge.Math, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abba2e25397ee8c9, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AForge.Math.2.2.5\lib\AForge.Math.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AForge.Vision, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b612fa915eefaa06, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AForge.Vision.2.2.5\lib\AForge.Vision.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SharpDX, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SharpDX.4.2.0\lib\net45\SharpDX.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SharpDX.Direct3D11, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SharpDX.Direct3D11.4.2.0\lib\net45\SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SharpDX.DXGI, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SharpDX.DXGI.4.2.0\lib\net45\SharpDX.DXGI.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsInput, Version=1.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de2685b4776e9c2e, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\InputSimulatorPlus.1.0.7\lib\net20\WindowsInput.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="DXGIScreenGrab.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainForm.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainForm.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainForm.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="MainForm.resx">
      <DependentUpon>MainForm.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: The project file is not in SDK style, so you are not supposed to use `dotnet` CLI to compile it. Please use MSBuild instead.

Comment: Thank you this resolved the compile issue.